# Why does DateTime.TryParseExact fail for "Jun", but work for all others?

Tags: .net, datetime

Here's my very simple parsing code:

```
var us = new CultureInfo("en-US");
var dateToParse = "Jun 1";
var isSuccessful = DateTime.TryParseExact(dateToParse, "MMMM d", us, DateTimeStyles.None, out DateTime date);
```

For some reason, the parsing fails just for "Jun". If I parse "May 1" (or any other date I tested) it works. Also "Jun" is the correct 3 letter abbreviation for June. It's even listed [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings?redirectedfrom=MSDN).

What am I doing wrong here?

Solution:
Thanks to @Damien_The_Unbeliever. He pointed out I was using "MMMM" instead of "MMM". Stupid mistake. But now it works.

Comment: Given you're using `MMMM` rather than `MMM`, why do you think the *abbreviated* name is relevant? It so happens that `May` is the complete name of a month as well as it's abbreviated name, so if that's the only other month you've tested, it's not surprising that it's worked.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever OMG. I'm so blind. Thank you. Of course this is the solution!

Comment: Rather than adding a "Solution" part in the *question*, please add an *answer*.

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

Thanks to @Damien_The_Unbeliever. He pointed out I was using "MMMM" instead of "MMM". Stupid mistake. But now it works.